# How can my husband travel to Europe while on a business visa to the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, schengen

My husband is on a business trip to London. His trip is getting extended for a couple of months, and he holds a visa until April 2018.

I tried to apply for a UK tourist visa, since it's our anniversary in January, so that I can visit him. I had my uncle sponsoring my trip and showed a bank balance of 150,000 INR from my end as well. My visa got rejected twice: the first time saying insufficient funds and the second time saying that I will not return back to India.

I am considering applying for a Schengen visa, but how can my husband come to Europe to visit me? He doesn't have a Schengen visa and I think he has to return back to India to apply for one. Is there any other possibility for us to meet?

Comment: Applying in London ought to be possible based on the fact that he will be there longer than three months and could not possibly apply earlier but he will have to pass the private visa outsourcing (VFS and co.) barrier first.